# Using AtomicReference for spring webflux without blocking

Tags: java, spring-webflux, race-condition, reactive

I want to set a `tenantId` value in the webflux, then use it in the logging something like this:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<String> getData(String id) {
        AtomicReference<String> tenantId = new AtomicReference<>();
        Mono<Resource> getResourceMono = resourceMapperService.getResource(id));
        return getResourceMono.flatMap(resource -> {
            tenantId.set(resource.getTenantId());
            Mono<String> result = uriConfigurationMono.flatMap(uriConfiguration -> getSearchData(resource.getServerId(),
                    uriConfiguration.getDataProxyUri(), id));
            return result;
        }).doFinally(response -> telemetryService.addLogging(tenantId, id);
    }
```

In here, I set `tenantId` as `AtomicReference<String>` then use it in `.doFinally`, hoping that `.doFinally` always happens after `tenantId.set(resource.getTenantId())`. Is it creating race condition?

If so, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: What if put `doFinally` `inside flatMap`, like `return result.doFinally()`?

Comment: Is there any difference in this example?

Comment: Then you would have `resource.getTenantId()` available in a lambda passed to `doFinally` and no AtomicReference would be needed.